# selecting a CoreData object and passing it as a Binding

Tags: swift, core-data, binding

This is a very simple question from a Swift beginner.

I need to select a default user in my scene delegate and pass it as a Binding to my app's main view.

The simplest version looks like this:

```
    let user = User.withEmail("alan@someplace.com", in: context)
    let contentView = MainTabbedView(user: user)
```

The problem is, "user" is an NSManagedObject of type User, it's not a Binding, so I get the error "Cannot convert value of type 'User' to expected argument type 'Binding'".

I can't put @Binding on my "let user" statement because I'm in the SceneDelegate's main function, so "user" is a local variable, and I need to be here (I think?) in order to use my CoreData context.

Comment: Maybe you should look into having user as an @EnvironmentObject.

Comment: Just to clarify, the User.withEmail call seems to work fine. The error occurs on the second line, when trying to pass "user", which is not a Binding.

Comment: Thank you, Joakim - but I still can't put an @EnvironmentObject property wrapper on a local var.

Comment: No you need to make User an ObservableObject and add @EnvironmentObject to the corresponding user property in MainTabbedView